# Custom checkout fields: Hiding/showing fields with a selector

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Based on this working answer:

```
 // Registering external jQuery/JS file
function cfields_scripts() {

    // IMPORTANT NOTE:
    // For a child theme replace get_template_directory_uri() by get_stylesheet_directory_uri()
    // The external cfields.js file goes in a subfolder "js" of your active child theme or theme.
    wp_enqueue_script( 'checkout_script', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/cfields.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cfields_scripts' );


add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'ba_custom_checkout_billing_fields' );
function ba_custom_checkout_billing_fields( $fields ) {

    // 1. Creating the additional custom billing fields

    // The "status" selector
    $fields['billing']['billing_status']['type'] = 'select';
    $fields['billing']['billing_status']['class'] = array('form-row-wide, status-select');
    $fields['billing']['billing_status']['required'] = true;
    $fields['billing']['billing_status']['label'] = __('Statut Juridic', 'theme_domain');
    $fields['billing']['billing_status']['placeholder'] = __('Alege statutul', 'theme_domain');
    $fields['billing']['billing_status']['options'] = array(
        '1' => __( 'Persoana Fizica', 'theme_domain' ),
        '2' => __( 'Persoana Juridica', 'theme_domain' )
    );

    // The "Nr. registrul comertului" text field (this field is common)
    $fields['billing']['billing_ser_id']['type'] = 'text';
    $fields['billing']['billing_ser_id']['class'] = array('form-row-wide', 'status-group2');
    $fields['billing']['billing_ser_id']['required'] = true; // <== HERE has to be "true" as it always be shown and need validation
    $fields['billing']['billing_ser_id']['label'] = __('Nr. Reg. Comert', 'theme_domain');
    $fields['billing']['billing_ser_id']['placeholder'] = __('Introdu numarul', 'theme_domain');

    // The "Banca" text field
    $fields['billing']['billing_bt_id']['type'] = 'text';
    $fields['billing']['billing_bt_id']['class'] = array('form-row-wide', 'status-group2');
    $fields['billing']['billing_bt_id']['required'] = false;
    $fields['billing']['billing_bt_id']['label'] = __('Banca', 'theme_domain');
    $fields['billing']['billing_bt_id']['placeholder'] = __('Adauga Banca', 'theme_domain');

    // The "IBAN" text field
    $fields['billing']['billing_ib_id']['type'] = 'text';
    $fields['billing']['billing_ib_id']['class'] = array('form-row-wide', 'status-group2');
    $fields['billing']['billing_ib_id']['required'] = false;
    $fields['billing']['billing_ib_id']['label'] = __('IBAN', 'theme_domain');
    $fields['billing']['billing_ib_id']['placeholder'] = __('Adauga IBAN-ul', 'theme_domain');

    // The "CIF" text field
    $fields['billing']['billing_cf_id']['type'] = 'text';
    $fields['billing']['billing_cf_id']['class'] = array('form-row-wide', 'status-group2');
    $fields['billing']['billing_cf_id']['required'] = false;
    $fields['billing']['billing_cf_id']['label'] = __('Cod Fiscal', 'theme_domain');
    $fields['billing']['billing_cf_id']['placeholder'] = __('Adauga CIF-ul', 'theme_domain');


    // 2. Ordering the billing fields

    $fields_order = array(
        'billing_first_name', 'billing_last_name', 'billing_email',
        'billing_phone',      'billing_address_1', 'billing_address_2',
        'billing_postcode',   'billing_city',      'billing_country',
        'billing_status',     'billing_company',   'billing_ser_id',
        'billing_bt_id',      'billing_ib_id',     'billing_cf_id'
    );

    foreach($fields_order as $field)
        $ordered_fields[$field] = $fields['billing'][$field];

    $fields['billing'] = $ordered_fields;


    // 4. Returning Checkout customized billing fields
    return $fields;

}


// Process the checkout (Checking if required fields are not empty)
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'ba_custom_checkout_field_process');
function ba_custom_checkout_field_process() {

    if ( ! $_POST['billing_ser_id'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( '<strong>Nr. Reg. Comert</strong> is a required field.', 'theme_domain' ), 'error' );

    if ( ! $_POST['billing_bt_id'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( '<strong>Banca</strong> is a required field.', 'theme_domain' ), 'error' );

    if ( ! $_POST['billing_ib_id'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( '<strong>IBAN</strong> is a required field.', 'theme_domain' ), 'error' );

    if ( ! $_POST['billing_cf_id'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( '<strong>Cod Fiscal</strong> is a required field.', 'theme_domain' ), 'error' );
}


// Adding/Updating meta data to the order with the custom-fields values
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'ba_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );
function ba_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {

    $billing_company = $_POST['billing_company'];
    $billing_ser_id  = $_POST['billing_ser_id'];
    $billing_bt_id   = $_POST['billing_bt_id'];
    $billing_ib_id   = $_POST['billing_ib_id'];
    $billing_cf_id   = $_POST['billing_cf_id'];

    // For Individual resetting billing company to "" (no value) instead of 'no'
    if ( !empty($billing_company) && 'no' == $billing_company )
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_company', '' );

    if ( !empty($billing_ser_id) )
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_ser_id', sanitize_text_field( $billing_ser_id ) );

    // Adding/updating data only for companies
    if ( !empty($billing_bt_id) && 'no' != $billing_bt_id )
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_bt_id', sanitize_text_field( $billing_bt_id ) );

    // Adding/updating data only for companies
    if ( !empty($billing_ib_id) && 'no' != $billing_ib_id )
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_ib_id', sanitize_text_field( $billing_ib_id ) );

    // Adding/updating data only for companies
    if ( !empty($billing_cf_id) && 'no' != $billing_cf_id )
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_cf_id', sanitize_text_field( $billing_cf_id ) );
}
```

To display the data on the customer order view, on Thankyou page, My account order view and on email notifications, add this 2 code snippets in your function.php file:

```
// Displaying data on order view in "customer details" zone
add_action('woocommerce_order_details_after_customer_details','ba_add_values_to_order_item_meta', 10, 1 );
function ba_add_values_to_order_item_meta( $order ) {

    $output = '';
    $billing_ser_id = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_billing_ser_id', true );
    $billing_bt_id  = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_billing_bt_id',  true );
    $billing_ib_id  = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_billing_ib_id',  true );
    $billing_cf_id  = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_billing_cf_id',  true );

    if ( !empty($billing_ser_id) )
        $output .= '
        <tr>
            <th>' . __( "Nr. Reg. Comert:", "woocommerce" ) . '</th>
            <td>' . $billing_ser_id . '</td>
        </tr>';

    if ( !empty($billing_bt_id) && 'no' != $billing_bt_id )
        $output .= '
        <tr>
            <th>' . __( "Banca:", "woocommerce" ) . '</th>
            <td>' . $billing_bt_id . '</td>
        </tr>';

    if ( !empty($billing_ib_id) && 'no' != $billing_ib_id )
        $output .= '
        <tr>
            <th>' . __( "IBAN:", "woocommerce" ) . '</th>
            <td>' . $billing_ib_id . '</td>
        </tr>';

    if ( !empty($billing_cf_id) && 'no' != $billing_cf_id )
        $output .= '
        <tr>
            <th>' . __( "Cod Fiscal:", "woocommerce" ) . '</th>
            <td>' . $billing_cf_id . '</td>
        </tr>';

    echo $output;
}


// Displaying data on email notifications
add_action('woocommerce_email_customer_details','ba_add_values_to_emails_notifications', 15, 4 );
function ba_add_values_to_emails_notifications( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {

    $output = '<ul>';
    $billing_ser_id = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_billing_ser_id', true );
    $billing_bt_id  = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_billing_bt_id',  true );
    $billing_ib_id  = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_billing_ib_id',  true );
    $billing_cf_id  = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_billing_cf_id',  true );

    if ( !empty($billing_ser_id) )
        $output .= '<li><strong>' . __( "Nr. Reg. Comert:", "woocommerce" ) . '</strong> <span class="text">' . $billing_ser_id . '</span></li>';

    if ( !empty($billing_bt_id) && 'no' != $billing_bt_id )
        $output .= '<li><strong>' . __( "Banca:", "woocommerce" ) . '</strong> <span class="text">' . $billing_bt_id . '</span></li>';

    if ( !empty($billing_ib_id) && 'no' != $billing_ib_id )
        $output .= '<li><strong>' . __( "IBAN:", "woocommerce" ) . '</strong> <span class="text">' . $billing_ib_id . '</span></li>';

    if ( !empty($billing_cf_id) && 'no' != $billing_cf_id )
        $output .= '<li><strong>' . __( "Cod Fiscal:", "woocommerce" ) . '</strong> <span class="text">' . $billing_cf_id . '</span></li>';
        $output .= '</ul>';

    echo $output;
}
```

Javascript cfields.js code (external file):

```js
// This file named "cfields.js" goes in a subfolder "js" of your active child theme or theme

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    // Common Serial ID field
    if(! $("#billing_ser_id_field").hasClass("validate-required") ){
        $("#billing_ser_id_field").addClass("validate-required");
    }


    // The 4 Fields to hide at start (if not "Persoana Juridica")
    if($("#billing_status option:selected").val() == "1"){
        $('#billing_company_field').hide(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
            $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
            $('#billing_company').val("no");
        });
        $('#billing_bt_id_field').hide(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
            $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
            $('#billing_bt_id').val("no");
        });
        $('#billing_ib_id_field').hide(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
            $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
            $('#billing_ib_id').val("no");
        });
        $('#billing_cf_id_field').hide(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
            $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
            $('#billing_cf_id').val("no");
        });
     }

    // Action with the selector (Showing/hiding and adding/removing classes)
    $("#billing_status").change(function(){
        // For "Persoana Juridica"
        if($("#billing_status option:selected").val() == "2")
        {
            $('#billing_company_field').show(function(){
                $(this).addClass("validate-required");
                $('#billing_company').val("");
            });
            $('#billing_bt_id_field').show(function(){
                $(this).children('label').append( ' <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr>' );
                $(this).addClass("validate-required");
                $('#billing_bt_id').val("");
            });
            $('#billing_ib_id_field').show(function(){
                $(this).children('label').append( ' <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr>' );
                $(this).addClass("validate-required");
                $('#billing_ib_id').val("");
            });
            $('#billing_cf_id_field').show(function(){
                $(this).children('label').append( ' <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr>' );
                $(this).addClass("validate-required");
                $('#billing_cf_id').val("");
            });
        }
        // For "Persoana Fizica"
        else if($("#billing_status option:selected").val() == "1")
        {
            $('#billing_company_field').hide(function(){
                $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
                $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
                $('#billing_company').val("no");
            });
            $('#billing_bt_id_field').hide(function(){
                $(this).children("abbr.required").remove();
                $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
                $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
                $('#billing_bt_id').val("no");
            });
            $('#billing_ib_id_field').hide(function(){
                $(this).children("abbr.required").remove();
                $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
                $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
                $('#billing_ib_id').val("no");
            });
            $('#billing_cf_id_field').hide(function(){
                $(this).children("abbr.required").remove();
                $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
                $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
                $('#billing_cf_id').val("no");
            });
        }

    });

});
```

So, my question is, how can I remove the common field "CNP" from the second option "Persoana Juridica"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to change in your hooked function **`ba_custom_checkout_billing_fields`** this line value to **`false`** (instead of true):

```
$fields['billing']['billing_ser_id']['required'] = false;
```

Then we change this hooked function a bit too:

```
// Adding/Updating meta data to the order with the custom-fields values
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'ba_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );
function ba_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {

    $billing_company = $_POST['billing_company'];
    $billing_ser_id  = $_POST['billing_ser_id'];
    $billing_bt_id   = $_POST['billing_bt_id'];
    $billing_ib_id   = $_POST['billing_ib_id'];
    $billing_cf_id   = $_POST['billing_cf_id'];

    if ( !empty($billing_company) && 'no' == $billing_company )
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_company', '' );

    ## Here we add 'no' == $billing_ser_id to the condition
    if ( !empty($billing_ser_id) && 'no' == $billing_ser_id )
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_ser_id', sanitize_text_field( $billing_ser_id ) );

    if ( !empty($billing_bt_id) && 'no' != $billing_bt_id )
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_bt_id', sanitize_text_field( $billing_bt_id ) );

    if ( !empty($billing_ib_id) && 'no' != $billing_ib_id )
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_ib_id', sanitize_text_field( $billing_ib_id ) );

    if ( !empty($billing_cf_id) && 'no' != $billing_cf_id )
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_cf_id', sanitize_text_field( $billing_cf_id ) );
}
```

And you have to replace your external JS file by this updated one:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    // The 4 Fields to hide at start (if not "Persoana Juridica")
    if($("#billing_status option:selected").val() == "1"){
        $('#billing_company_field').hide(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
            $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
            $('#billing_company').val("no");
        });
        $('#billing_bt_id_field').hide(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
            $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
            $('#billing_bt_id').val("no");
        });
        $('#billing_ib_id_field').hide(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
            $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
            $('#billing_ib_id').val("no");
        });
        $('#billing_cf_id_field').hide(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
            $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
            $('#billing_cf_id').val("no");
        });
     }

    // Action with the selector (Showing/hiding and adding/removing classes)
    $("#billing_status").change(function(){
        // For "Persoana Juridica"
        if($("#billing_status option:selected").val() == "2")
        {
            $('#billing_company_field').show(function(){
                $(this).addClass("validate-required");
                $('#billing_company').val("");
            });
            $('#billing_bt_id_field').show(function(){
                $(this).children('label').append( ' <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr>' );
                $(this).addClass("validate-required");
                $('#billing_bt_id').val("");
            });
            $('#billing_ib_id_field').show(function(){
                $(this).children('label').append( ' <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr>' );
                $(this).addClass("validate-required");
                $('#billing_ib_id').val("");
            });
            $('#billing_cf_id_field').show(function(){
                $(this).children('label').append( ' <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr>' );
                $(this).addClass("validate-required");
                $('#billing_cf_id').val("");
            });
            // Hide Serial ID field
            $('#billing_ser_id_field').hide(function(){
                $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
                $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
                $('#billing_ser_id').val("no");
            });
        }
        // For "Persoana Fizica"
        else if($("#billing_status option:selected").val() == "1")
        {
            $('#billing_company_field').hide(function(){
                $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
                $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
                $('#billing_company').val("no");
            });
            $('#billing_bt_id_field').hide(function(){
                $(this).children("abbr.required").remove();
                $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
                $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
                $('#billing_bt_id').val("no");
            });
            $('#billing_ib_id_field').hide(function(){
                $(this).children("abbr.required").remove();
                $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
                $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
                $('#billing_ib_id').val("no");
            });
            $('#billing_cf_id_field').hide(function(){
                $(this).children("abbr.required").remove();
                $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
                $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
                $('#billing_cf_id').val("no");
            });
            // Showing Serial ID field
            $('#billing_ser_id_field').show(function(){
                $(this).children('label').append( ' <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr>' );
                $(this).addClass("validate-required");
                $('#billing_ser_id').val("");
            });
        }

    });

});
```

This way the Serial ID custom field will only appear when **`'Persoana Fizica'`** is selected and will be in this case only a required field.

This last change is untested, but these are the kind of changes to do.

Comment: And now I need to hide also the personal name for *Persoana Juridica*